# Qt Game Editor - Build Game to Executable?

Tags: qt, game-engine

I apologize in advance for my overall "noobness." This is my first question on stack overflow, and I am quite new to Qt, and game editor programming as well. That said, I do feel that my programming skill is not too far behind.

I've been looking for a question like this for two days, both on and off this website, and haven't found a single one. That could be because I don't know the right words to describe what I'm looking for simply.

I am beginning to build a simple game editor and engine with Qt. Please do not give the response of "Do you really want to make a game editor/engine" or "don't". I have my reasons why I am sure this is what I want to create. My question has to do with the "export to executable" or "build" feature that editors have. I've been trying to wrap my head around it, but I don't know how I would even begin to make that work. For all I know it could be one line of code, or ten-thousand.

Can someone please just point me in the right direction for what kind of programming I would need to do to make that work? If it's difficult and involves concepts I don't already know, that is actually kind of a good thing, because it means more learning for me. I just need some direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is entirely too broad, and contrary to what you may claim, from what you claim it is quite obvious that you are getting ahead of yourself. You wouldn't be asking those questions if you had the knowledge and experience needed to accomplish such a task. Keep in mind questions that are too broad and questions about recommendations of books, libraries or tutorials are offtopic on SO.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that this is considered off-topic here. But can you tell me why this is considered too broad? I don't understand what's wrong with asking for direction on a forum. I was not asking for book recommendations. I apologize if I gave that impression. I was asking for which specific topics of programming i should research to figure this out. The purpose of my game engine project is to learn all of the skills and gain all of the knowledge required to accomplish this. I have a background in programming games, which is why I want to learn this side of software.

Comment: Just search for StackOverflow mentions on Hacker News, you'll know why :)

Comment: Export  / build function / feature will probably do compilation / packaging of stuff, which means, external processes will be launched via QProcess, with output potentially parsed and, in any case, presented to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alone "If it's difficult and involves concepts I don't already know" is enough to close this question. As if we know what you know and don't know...

Game editors are in general separated from the actual game building process that creates an executable as the final product. This is due to the overall complexity of putting all parts of the production chain into a single piece of software.

That said you can "connect" an editor to the building tools that you have to use in order to produce an executable. There are examples for this like the Unity SDK (including Unity Engine, Unity Editor etc.).

A huge exception to this general practice is [Adventure Game Studio](http://www.adventuregamestudio.co.uk/), which went open-source since not that long ago. I do believe that AGS is using `.NET` and `C#` in particular. It is almost all-in-one package including a built-in tool for generating executables from its custom language and adding the engine to it. It seems that this is what you are looking for though the complexity of such piece of software might be intimidating. If it's too much you can of course simply try to seamlessly add external building tools to your editor. `Qt Creator` is a nice example for this as well as probably 99% of all IDEs out there - editor simply provides the interface to interact with the building tools which **are not** part of it.

Last but not least you have to consider the maintenance that will be required in the future. Integrating the building infrastructure in your editor might seem like a good idea at first however what happens when you want to replace relatively large chunks of code in either your editor or this same building infrastructure, or even in both? My suggestion is to create the editor and just add an interfacing mechanism to existing building tools, which can easily be changed without ruining your editor's code or the one that represents your set of building tools.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into existing building tools and connecting them.

Answer (score 1):

In practice game editors do not build games to executable, they merely package game scripts and resources into a format the already implemented game executable can read. The game executable is not created by the game editor, it is implemented conventionally.

That being said, you might want to compile game scripts to native - in that case you must bundle the used compiled with the game, and invoke it from a child process to compile the script code to a shared library plugin, which you can dynamically load and use in the game engine. There is no magic here, whether it is a game or any other application, it is the same basic stuff.

In short, the game editor does not build executables - compilers do. Not unless you want, in addition to a game engine, also create your own C++ compiler too ;)

Comment: Thank you! This (and rbaleksandar's answer) really helps. I think I understand what I need to do now.